# Is energy since the big-bang still here in the present?

Tags: energy, big-bang

Based on the concept that energy can never be destroyed and is only transferred. Does it mean that energy since the formation of literally everything still here today?

Comment: Yes.  The Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) radiation. Also, all matter and everything else.